# How to Display all the Available Shipping Countries in a Column in Products list WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, country

I am using [ALD – Dropshipping and Fulfillment for AliExpress and WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-alidropship/) plugin. Is there any way to display all available shipping countries for a product, in Admin product list new column (I mean a column that contains list of all countries that are available for shipping in each product).

I tried a plugin named //Product Visibility by Country for WooCommerce// displays a column for countries, but the problem with this plugin is that you should add manually the available countries for each product.

I am asking if there is a function to display the countries that are already linked with each product.

In my case, I am using plugins to import data from different sources, and the products came automatically with the available shipping countries. So now, it is not easy to know which countries that are available for each product, I can only know by visiting the checkout page and do a manual check for each country.

I hope there is a function to display them in a column in the products list.

Comment: I thought it is possible since the data can be found in the checkout page. (When I choose an unavailable country in checkout page, the prdocut become unavailable)
If woocommerce can filtre which country is available for each product, I assumed that it can be filtered with a function as well. Nothing magical in here.

Comment: Also, when I added the Google listings and ads plugin, the available shipping countries for each product appeared in the Google merchant center automatically.
I assumed that there is a meta_key or a meta_value that contains the available shipping countries in the WooCommerce core.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec By the way, I tried all your suggestions that I found on other stack overflow answers, but nothing worked.

Comment: There are not any WooCommerce shipping locations set at the product level. This feature could be enabled by 3rd Party plugin, but doesn't exist in WooCommerce default core.

Comment: I am using a Plugin named ALD aliexpress Dropshipping and Fulfillment. the plugin automatically imports shipping countries to products.
I checked the postmeta on the database (based on your suggestion in other people's posts) but I could not find the meta_key that can make the function work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KargWare The plugin that is mentioned in the post is more complex and involves codes that modify the shipping behaviour. I contacted the developer of the plugin and asked him about the meta_key that retrieves the country data from the plugin for each product, he wrote to me :
You can use this key: _vi_wad_shipping_info
It’s for before migrating data to the new table, if you’ve migrated, please do it in the corresponding table instead.
I wrote new functions but nothing worked.

Comment: @KargWare I contacted him again, and told me :
Since our plugin meta key is not post type of product. Its post type is “vi_wad_draft_product”
>> So if you’re using post type of product, it’ll return N/A

In his answer, he explained why I got N/A in the function that I used with a condition :
 } else {
echo ‘N/A’; // Display N/A if shipping info or country data is not found or not in the expected format
}
} else {
echo ‘N/A’; // Display N/A if the shipping_info field is empty
}

Comment: I can't send the functions that I used as replies because of the 600-character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shipping countries' data is imported from AliExpress using the plugin,
To achieve the goal of displaying all available countries in a column, we must analyze all countries in each individual product page (because AliExpress has an individual page for each country) and filter which country is available and which country is unavailable, and generate the data.
That will be complex and take more resources.
However, You can use the code below the display the main shipping country that was chosen to import products, this code only displays one country and not all the available shipping countries.

```js
// Add a custom column to the product list in the WordPress admin
            function add_shipping_country_column( $columns ) {
                $columns['shipping_country'] = 'Shipping Country';

                return $columns;
            }

            add_filter( 'manage_product_posts_columns', 'add_shipping_country_column' );

    // Populate the custom column with shipping country data from the "_vi_wad_shipping_info" custom field
            function populate_shipping_country_column( $column, $post_id ) {
                if ( $column == 'shipping_country' ) {

                    $ali_import_id = VI_WOOCOMMERCE_ALIDROPSHIP_DATA::product_get_id_by_woo_id( $post_id );
    // Get the post type to check if it's a product or another post type

    // Get the shipping information from the "_vi_wad_shipping_info" custom field
                    $shipping_info = ALD_Product_Table::get_post_meta( $ali_import_id, '_vi_wad_shipping_info', true );

    // Check if the shipping_info field exists and contains data
                    if ( ! empty( $shipping_info ) ) {
    // Unserialize the data
                        $shipping_info_data = maybe_unserialize( $shipping_info );

    // Check if the 'country' key exists
                        if ( isset( $shipping_info_data['country'] ) ) {
                            $shipping_country = $shipping_info_data['country'];

    // Display the shipping country
                            echo esc_html( $shipping_country );
                        } else {
                            echo 'N/A'; // Display N/A if the 'country' key is not found
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'N/A'; // Display N/A if the shipping_info field is empty
                    }

                }
            }

            add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'populate_shipping_country_column', 10, 2 );
```